# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Already read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got this error:

> sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_b854c4b93cc10a271230fd4a9e7b2b9b.js:661
>   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Already read
>       at t.e.json (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_b854c4b93cc10a271230fd4a9e7b2b9b.js:661)
>       at ListItemFactory.ts:81
>       at

Code line where the error is thrown is here:

```
 .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
```

The entire class is:

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { IWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { IListItem} from "./models/IListItem";
import { IFactory } from "./IFactory";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    // private _listItems: IListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): Promise<any[]> {
        switch(listName) {
            case "GenericList":
                let items: IListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        {
                            // key: v.id,
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "News":
                let newsitems: INewsListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,newsheader,newsbody,expiryDate,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: INewsListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: INewsListItem[] }) => {
                    return newsitems=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            newsheader: v.newsheader,
                            newsbody: v.newsbody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Announcements":
                let announcementitems: IAnnouncementListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,announcementBody,expiryDate,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }) => {
                    return announcementitems=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            announcementBody: v.announcementBody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Directory":
                let directoryitems: IDirectoryListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,firstName,lastName,mobileNumber,internalNumber,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IDirectoryListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] }) => {
                    return directoryitems=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        {
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            firstName: v.firstName,
                            lastName: v.lastName,
                            mobileNumber: v.mobileNumber,
                            internalNumber: v.internalNumber
                        }
                    ));
                });
            default:
                break;
            }
      }
}
```

Please note that this is a Sharepoint webpart with ReactJS, where the user selects a list from the property pane, the first time the webpart is rendered, it takes data from the GenericList which is the default, then the user can select another list like Announcements, and there is where I get the error when the user selects a different list

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to use `break;` at the end of each case, instead it'll run all cases after the first reached.

Answer (score 8):

You're calling `response.json()` twice. That's not allowed in `fetch()`.

If you want to know what's in the response, use `text()`, to read and parse it yourself, in case it's not valid json. (You can use `text()` only once too, but if `JSON.parse()` fails, you'll still know why.) This is probably not your problem though. You're just reading the response body twice, and that's a nono with `fetch()`.

Reproduce in JS in your console:

```
fetch('/').then(rsp => {
  rsp.json().then(console.log); // << invalid json, probably
  rsp.json().then(console.log); // << already read
})
```

(One error will be 'invalid json', but that's not relevant.) Other error will be 'already read'.

The reason behind the reason is in your lib. `requester.get` probably reads the response, so you can't. Maybe `SPHttpClientResponse` has some other method/property to read it.

Comment: I am calling resposen.json but in different switches statements so they will never be executed twice.

Comment: Apparently they are. Probably once in your code, and once in the parent lib.